# How can I query something with points in variables?

Tags: sql

For my site there is a `loginsystem` where you need to login with your `emailadress`, but the problem is that my query gives an error when I start writing my `emailadress` whenever I use a point.

Here is my query:

```
  $sql = "SELECT LeerlingID FROM tblLeerlingen WHERE email = '$myusername' and Wachtwoord = '$mypassword'";
```

Comment: You need to quote the strings, like `WHERE email = 'gregoor.maarten.mg@gmail.com' and Wachtwoord = '0dc22c6a909acf658232f6a38e780d7b'`

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Do not munge query strings with user input.

Comment: but  the user needs to fill in the fields to log in @GordonLinoff

Comment: Nah, he is talking about SQL Injection, you may consider reading this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your strings properly:

```
SELECT LeerlingID FROM tblLeerlingen WHERE email = 'gregoor.maarten.mg@gmail.com' and Wachtwoord = '0dc22c6a909acf658232f6a38e780d7b';
```

Comment: this is just the paste of my attempt in phpMyAdmin, in my code I have;

SELECT LeerlingID FROM tblLeerlingen WHERE email = '$myusername' and Wachtwoord = '$mypassword'

Comment: Please edit your real code and the error into the question then.

Comment: Why just duplicate comment?

Comment: @SouXin I posted the answer at 2019-04-05 18:07:41Z, the comment was posted at 2019-04-05 18:08:46Z.

Comment: @maio290 Sorry than

Comment: The error is still missing. The SQL looks OK, so it's something else.

Comment: Very bad advice!!!  You should be explaining how and why to use parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I really won't give anyone the talk about SQL injection, it's the second post at related questions.